# How to set SSH config to grab part of ssh hostname and use as variable?

Tags: ssh

I'm SSH'ing into multiple datacenters that are setup identically. Each datacenter has a jumpbox, and behind that there's access to various db servers etc.

It's a pain to manually specify entries for all these servers, when they're almost identical across datacenters, other than the jumpbox IP. So I'd like to set my `.ssh/config` file so that I can type `datacenter_name-server_behind_jumpbox` and have SSH grab the `datacenter_name` off the front of the host (so that I can re-use it in the `ProxyCommand`.

For example, if I want to access the Maria server in datacenter1, I'd create an SSH entry for the jumpbox called `datacenter1`. Then for the Maria server behind it, I'd setup something like:

```
Host %dc%-maria
    Hostname maria
    User jeff
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p %dc
```

That way I only need to setup a single entry for each type of server that's located behind the jumpbox, and it automatically knows which datacenter jumpbox to hit.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You can use glob-style patterns (eg `Host *-maria`), but there does not appear to be a way to capture the matching part of the hostname for use in the configuration.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/26422/115583

Answer (score 5):

I add a fake suffix to the hostname with different proxy hosts

```
Host *.dc1
    ProxyCommand ssh -q %r@dc1 -W %h:%p

Host *.dc2
    ProxyCommand ssh -q %r@dc2 -W %h:%p
```

Then do something like ssh server1.dc1 and it will use the proxy host.

You can add Host entries for custom settings like this:

```
Host server1.*
    User jeff
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run a script as a custom ProxyCommand and do your works before the *real* ProxyCommand:

`.ssh/config`:

```
Host *-maria
    Hostname maria
    User jeff          
    ProxyCommand /bin/datacenter_ssh.sh %h %p
```

`datacenter_ssh.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMBINED=$1
DATACENTER=$(echo $COMBINED | cut -d'-' -f1)
SERVER=$(echo $COMBINED | cut -d'-' -f2)
PORT=$2

ssh -q -W $SERVER:$PORT $DATACENTER
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar situation and doing something like this:

```
# configuration for the datacenter, can add entries for each datacenter
Host datacenter_name
    HostName <datacenter_ip>
    User <datacenter_user>
    IdentityFile <datacenter_keyfile>

# usage match: datacenter_name-server_behind_jumpbox
Host *-*
    User <server_behind_jumpbox user>
    IdentityFile <server_behind_jumpbox keyfile>
    Port <server_behind_jumpbox port>
    ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | cut -d- -f1) nc $(echo %h | cut -d- -f2) %p"
```

Of course you could also do something more like you described

```
# usage match: datacenter_name-maria, specify one for each server
Host *-maria
    User <maria user>
    IdentityFile <maria keyfile>
    Port <maria port>
    ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | cut -d- -f1) nc $(echo %h | cut -d- -f2) %p"
```