# How to edit the middle of host name (%h) in ssh config?

Tags: ssh, configuration, unix

In ssh config you can easily edit a hostname by appending or prepending it with something. For example, when you want to connect to server with `ssh test5`, but actually the server name is test5.mail, you can specify the server as like this:

```
Match exec "echo %h | grep -q '^test[0-9]$'"
    HostName %h.mail
```

The same approach could be applied if you need to prepend hostname.

But what if I want to edit the middle of the hostname? For example, I want to connect as `ssh server1.storage`, but the actual address I want to connect to is server1.int.storage.

In other words, I want to insert substring in the middle of %h.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
Match exec "echo %h | grep -q '^server[0-9]*.storage$'"
    ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | sed 's/storage/int.storage/') nc $(echo %h | sed 's/storage/int.storage/') %p
```

I have found example of proxy command in this [question](https://serverfault.com/a/1020978/484655). But I do not completely understand why you need that part with nc and %p. There you specify the edit command twice. I would like to just specify it once, like this:

```
ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | sed 's/storage/int.storage/')
```

but it is not working.

From the same question linked above, I see that you can also specify the handler script. But it seems the command again should be specified with twice ediding. So I would rather prefer to keep everything in one place - in the ssh config itself.

Would appreciate explanation and other variants of solutions, if any.

Answer (score 0):

you can just the nc bit in proxycommand without repeating ssh

```
Match exec "echo %h | grep -q '^server[0-9]*.storage$'"
    ProxyCommand nc $(echo %h | sed 's/storage/int.storage/') %p
```

in my case i used it for non dns resolvable aws ec2 names

```
Match exec "echo %n | grep -qE '^ip-.*\.compute\.internal$'"
ProxyCommand nc $(echo %n | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d- -f2- | tr - .) %p
```